# Hourly sales into Reporting Services view, SQL

Tags: sql, reporting-services, left-join

I have a table: Hourly_Sales that is like this (counting how many buy something and the ID check):

```
Store    Time    Year   Month     Count_Service    Count_Service_ID_Check
00001    09:00   2011   8         40               3
00001    10:00   2011   8         50               5
00001    15:00   2011   8         50               5
```

Now I want to be able to display it like this in Reporting Services:

```
                       09:00   10:00    11:00    12:00    13:00    14:00    15:00
Store: 00001    
Count_Service          40      50       0        0         0       0        50
Count_Service_ID_Check 3       5        0        0         0       0        5
```

That is I want to add the hours where there are no transactions, and add a 0.

I have a time table: Dim_TimeTable
That is populated with time and store id:

```
Store   Time
00001   09:00
00001   10:00
00001   11:00
00001   12:00
00001   13:00
00001   14:00
00001   15:00
```

Shouldn´t it be enough to do a LEFT JOIN on the Hourly_Sales?

I found a simular question but couldn´t get the answer for my problem for it:
[SQL Query to return 24 hour, hourly count even when no values exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375111/sql-query-to-return-24-hour-hourly-count-even-when-no-values-exist)

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - use:

```
select t.store, t.time, s.Count_Service, s.Count_Service_ID_Check
from Dim_TimeTable t
left join Hourly_Sales s on t.store = s.store and t.time = s.time
```

as your query, then use a matrix to display time across the page.